# MKMapkit route is misaligned or not in the centre of road

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkplacemark

I am developing an application in which I need to draw a route between two points using lat/long.

I have used apple API to get polylines and drawing it after decoding it.

Problem:

1. Route is not in the middle of the road (Attached image_1) or route is misaligned

[image]

[image]

Below is the code:

```
    NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",self.lat1.text,self.long1.text];

    NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",self.lat2.text,self.long2.text];

    NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false", saddr, daddr];

    NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


    NSData *responseData = [apiResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSError* error1;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                           error:&error1];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@",[error1 localizedDescription],[error1 localizedFailureReason]);


   if([[json objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        NSArray *routes1 = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
        NSDictionary *route = [routes1 lastObject];

        if (route)
        {
            NSString *overviewPolyline = [[route objectForKey: @"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];

            routes = [self decodePolyLine:overviewPolyline];

            //NSLog(@"%@",[routes objectAtIndex:0]);

            [self updateRouteView];
            [self centerMap];
        }
    }


-(void) updateRouteView
{
 NSInteger numberOfSteps = routes.count;

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
    CLLocation *location = [routes objectAtIndex:index];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

    coordinates[index] = coordinate;
}

MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
[self.mapView addOverlay:polyLine];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same problem you described in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809898/mapkit-draw-route-problems/15823436?noredirect=1#comment22752218_15823436) and it has the same solution. You are using data from two different sources, and the data is different.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your inputs. route is misaligned in the map. In android app, using same API and even overlay_polylines provided by google are same and route is in centre in android map but same route is misaligned in iOS.

Comment: That's exactly my point. In iOS you are using Google's route and drawing it on Apple's road data, the two are not the same. On Android you are using Google's route on top of Google's roads. Those two are aligned.

Comment: I understand your point Craig. I also tried to use APPLE Map API "http://maps.apple.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=true"; and got same polyline and same output. Route is misaligned. Now here is both MAP kit and map api are both from APPLE. Any comments

Comment: I mentioned this on the other question the URL you have given does contain "apple.com" but it redirects to Google. It's a hang over from iOS 5 days when Google also provided the road data for mapkit, but they don't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**decodePolyLine** is totally depend n the **latitude** and **longitude** you get. So if you get proper **latitude** and **longitude** then this case will not happen. Another reason for that tis from **iOS6** and above **apple** is using it's own map so may be they have different **latitude** and **longitude** from the **Google** map.

Comment: Thanks @Yashesh. But with the same GOOGLE API & lat/long, the android map is displaying route correctly. Is there any issues with precision of lat/long (6/9 digits)?

Comment: from iOS6 and above Google map and Apple may have some different result.